# Is there an analytic solution to a two-bodied gravitational system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find a general solution to the following system of ODEs:

$\ddot{x}=\frac{-x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \\
\ddot{y}=\frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \\
x(0)=0, \dot{x}(0)=-.25,y(0)=1,\dot{y}(0)=.5 \\
\text{where }\ddot{x}=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2},\ddot{y}=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$

I've been trying to work out an analytic solution but cannot find one. I have worked out a numerical solution using Mathematica. Is there a technique I should be using for this, I am new to solving systems of ODE's.

Comment: Change to the center of mass frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT : Change to polar coordinates.

The general solution is given below. Continue for computing the parameters $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ according to the given initial conditions.

Note : some parameters can be real or complex, depending on the elliptic or hyperbolic trajectory.

The integrals obtained below can be written on close forms with elementary functions.

[image]

Addition to the first answer, with conditions $x(0)=0,y(0)=1,x'(0)=-1/4,y'(0)=1/2$ :

Obviously, $\rho(0)=1$ and $\theta(0)=\pi/2$. Putting these values into the above equations $x'(\rho,\theta)$ and $y'(\rho,\theta)$ leads to $\rho'(0)=1/2$ and $\theta'(0)=1/4$

$$\theta'(0)=\frac{c_1}{\rho(0)^2}=\frac{1}{4}=\frac{c_1}{1^2} \quad\to\quad c_1=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\rho'(0)=\frac{1}{\rho(0)}\sqrt{c_2\rho(0)^2+2\rho(0)-c_1^2}=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{1}\sqrt{c_2(1)^2+2(1)-(1/4)^2} \quad\to\quad c_2=-\frac{27}{16}$$

With the lower bound $=1$ of the integrals, one can set $c_3=0$ and $c_4=\pi/2$ so that : $\rho(t=0)=1$ and $\theta(t=0)=\theta(\rho=1)=\pi/2$

Comment: I am able to work through all of this and understand it. I don't see how to transform the initial conditions in order to solve for the constants now. For the parametric solution with the initial conditions, I would have $t=0, r=1$ right? And for the Trajectory equation, I have $\theta = \pi /2$ and $r=1$ right? Or am I misunderstanding how to solve for the constants?

Comment: $\theta(0)=\pi/2$ and $\rho(0)=1$ are OK. You have to find $\theta'(0)=1/2$ and $\rho'(0)=-1/4$ from $x'(0)=-1/4$ and $y'(0)=1/2$ , thanks to the formulas of $x'$ and $y'$ given above.

Comment: But how do I then use these in the general equations? Or do I use them on the earlier equations such as $\theta' = \frac{c1}{\rho^2}$?

Comment: See the addition to the previous answer.

Comment: Did you mix up your $\rho'(0)$ and $\theta'(0)$? I got $x'(0)=-1/4 = \rho'(0)cos(\pi /2)- \rho sin(\pi/2) \theta'(0) = \rho'(0) (0) - (1)(1)\theta'(0)$ so $\theta'(0) = 1/4$ and $y'(0) = 1/2 = \rho'(0) sin(pi/2) + \rho cos(pi/2) \theta'(0) = \rho'(0)$.

Comment: Also, on the integrals for solving for $c3, c4$ you set the bounds equal to $1, \rho$ so the integral is equal to $0$ at $t=0$ because $\rho(0) =1$ right? I've never seen this technique, interesting.

Comment: And one final thing: How can I plot or make calculations from these? Like if I wanted to calculate $\rho$ or $\theta$ at a certain time. Sorry, I just haven't ran into a problem like this before.

Comment: You are right, there was some mistakes, now corrected. Since the results are on parametric form (parameter $\rho$), numerical calculus is required. One have to compute $t$ and $\theta$ for successive numerical values of $\rho$.

Comment: So, if I wanted to find a time when $\rho$ is equal to a certain value, or find the maximum and minimum of $\rho$, this is impossible analytically?

Comment: The extremums of $\rho$ are given by $c_2\rho^2+2\rho-c_1^2=0$ since the square root must be real.

Comment: ahhh, I was just thinking that looking back at the equations. Thank you for all your help!